# Django can't find user with 'python manage.py changepassword'

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I've got some code (using Python 3.4, Django 1.7, and PostgreSQL) that I pushed to Heroku. Everything worked fine until I added a login. Just like on my local machine, I used the shell to add a user, create a password, and save the user/password. That pattern worked locally, even with foreman.

**The setup that seems to have worked:**

```
heroku run python3 manage.py shell
a = User.objects.get(id=1)
a
```

The server returns

```
<User: {'username':'Me'}>.
```

Asking for `a.password` returns a hashed password that changes when I do `a.set_password('Blah')` and then `a.save()`.

**That's all good and normal, except** that the username/password (unhashed) won't log me in. When I run:

```
heroku run python3 manage.py changepassword Me
```

Heroku responds with:

```
CommandError: user 'Me' does not exist
```

How can a user be saved and retrievable in the shell, implying it's in the database, but not be found otherwise using "manage.py changepassword"?

Most importantly, how can I log into my website on Heroku?

****Edit****
I ran `python manage.py createsuperuser` in the Heroku shell to create a user so I could log in. Once I did, I saw that none of my CSS loaded. I'm not sure how that's related, but two big problems at the same time make me suspicious that it's something totally unrelated.

Comment: Are you able to assess if other data is available on the website itself/other manage.py commands? Just to ensure you're actually using the same database? No clue why it'd be a problem but it's the only thing that comes to mind.

Comment: Also, make sure a custom user model isn't defined in settings.py. Again, no clue how it'd be a problem.

Comment: try `django-admin changepassword Me` ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-changepassword

Comment: The shell grabs other data from the database, so it's connected. I'll remove the `@login_required` to see if it works from the website. Also, I had stubbed out a custom user model, but it didn't have anything real yet. I commented it out and ran a new migration, but still have the same problem.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7.0, and when I run `django-admin help`, it doesn't list `changepassword` as an available subcommand. I'll try updating Django and see if that gives me `changepassword`, but it seems that manage.py uses django-admin to run its commands, so I'd be surprised if that worked.